# Multi Conditionals (OR and AND inside AND) in addAttributeToFilter

Tags: filter, addattributetofilter

How to create a multi-condition in addAttributeToFilter?

I want result in a SQL query like this (image attached) :

```
WHERE ((`e`.`news_from_date` > '2013-09-12') OR (`e`.`news_to_date` < '2013-09-12'))
AND ((((`e`.`special_price` IS NULL))) OR (((`e`.`special_price` IS NOT NULL)) AND ((`e`.`special_from_date` < '2013-09-12') OR (`e`.`special_to_date` > '2013-09-12'))))

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('null'=>'special_price'), 'left');
```

Thank you[image]

Comment: I found this very useful: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-join-filter-select-and-sort-attributes-fields-and-tables/#crayon-5ce7b066c591f710554943

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should be able to combine most of these techniques to create the query you want. For sales tables, you probably will use `addFieldToFilter` - but `Zend_Db_Expr` is likely the path of least resistance for you :

**addAttributeToFilter :**

[According to the Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento) : When creating parentheticals that have `OR` conditions you can do the following:

> If an array is passed but no attribute code specified, it will be interpreted as a group of OR conditions that will be processed in the same way.

So, from that we can construct the following :

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=> 'someattribute','like' => 'value'),
        array('attribute'=> 'otherattribute','like' => 'value'),
        array('attribute'=> 'anotherattribute','like' => 'value'),
    )
);
```

This will output a `WHERE` clause of the format :

```
WHERE ((someattribute LIKE 'value') OR (otherattribute LIKE 'value') OR (anotherattribute LIKE 'value'))
```

**addFieldToFilter :**

In the case where the model is directly linked to a DB table, the following is required for applying conditionals to the database column by name :

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    array('title', 'content'),
    array(
        array('like'=>'%$titlesearchtext%'), 
        array('like'=>'%$contentsearchtext%')
    )
)
```

**Zend_Db_Expr :**

For much more complicated constructs you can build your own where clause using `Zend_Db_Expr`. For instance :

```
$collection->getSelect()->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("(e.created_at > '2013-01-01 00:00:00' OR e.created_at <'2012-01-01 00:00:00)"));
```

---

Source :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301231/addattributetofilter-and-or-condition-in-magentos-collection

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826474/magento-addfieldtofilter-two-fields-match-as-or-not-and/7851884#7851884

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the thing that I want is to make condition like: WHERE (CONDITION_1 OR (CONDITION_2 AND (CONDITION_3 OR CONDITION_4))). I already post the query that I want above.

Comment: I thought I made the point that you can use `Zend_Db_Expr`: `$collection->getSelect()->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("(CONDITION_1 OR (CONDITION_2 AND (CONDITION_3 OR CONDITION_4)))"));`

Comment: thanks philwinkle.base on your answer, this is sample what i did with addAttributeToFilter and AND and OR condition: http://pastebin.com/ZznxLAai

Comment: Is there a way to determine which attribute produced a result? I am searching a custom model collection across three fields (`name`, `altnernate_name`, `description`) and would like to know when a result is because of the `description` attribute.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to include **AND** with the combination of **OR** then

```
$colemanManufacturerSku = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku_1')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku_2')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku_3')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
    // Above condition will AND with following OR
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array(
                'attribute' => 'sku_1',
                'neq' => ''
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'sku_2',
                'neq' => ''
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'sku_3',
                'neq' => ''
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: +1 for your solution, but I need exactly opposite, i.e. WHERE (CONDITION_1 And CONDITION_2) OR (CONDITION_3 AND CONDITION_4))), Can you please help

Answer (score 1):

**Or condition using addFieldToFilter**

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter
                (   
                    array('email','mobile'),
                    array($emaiId,$mobNum)
                );
```