# Admin product grid filtered by multi SKUs

Tags: product, admin, grid

I need to find a way to enhance the admin products grid with capability to fill in the SKU field more than one reference.

For example, get copy/paste from an Excel list multiple sku and get the matching list on Magento.

I've already a solution in place based on default grid block rewriting but there is a conflict with a new cleaner extension I want to use with (Enhanced Admin Grids from Magento connect).

What is the best way to achieve this? Rewriting how the default sku field is working or adding a new custom one?

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion adding a new custom clumn is better because of two reasons:

1. The core team may modify the existing `sku` column any time. Additionally, as you said any extension developer may rewrite this grid or more specific this column given it's a very basic one. If you create your own column probably nobody else knows about it what makes it less likely that somebody will screw around with your column
2. It's hard (if not impossible) to modify the existing columns without rewrites or observer a very generic event and therefore possibly slowing down the page generation.

Having said that and contra-dicting myself there is a way to use a product-grid-specific event and modify the original `sku` column. You should document this though as it's not very intuitive if you find the code again two years later.

The solution is: observe the event `adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction` amd manipulate the already existing column.

1. I'll assume that you created an extension before so I'll skip Magento extension creation basics. I call my example extension `Emzee_MultiSkuFilter`.
2. **Add an observer for `adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction`** in `app/code/local/Emzee/MultiSkuFilter/etc/config.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Emzee_MultiSkuFilter>
               <version>1.0.0</version>
           </Emzee_MultiSkuFilter>
       </modules>
       <adminhtml>
           <events>
               <adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction>
                   <observers>
                       <emzee_multiskufilter>
                           <class>emzee_multiskufilter/observer</class>
                           <method>adminhtmlCatalogProductGridPrepareMassaction</method>
                       </emzee_multiskufilter>
                   </observers>
               </adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction>
           </events>
       </adminhtml>
       <global>
           <models>
               <emzee_multiskufilter>
                   <class>Emzee_MultiSkuFilter_Model</class>
                   <resourceModel>emzee_multiskufilter_resource</resourceModel>
               </emzee_multiskufilter>
               <emzee_multiskufilter_resource>
                   <class>Emzee_MultiSkuFilter_Model_Resource</class>
               </emzee_multiskufilter_resource>
           </models>
           <helpers>
               <emzee_multiskufilter>
                   <class>Emzee_MultiSkuFilter_Helper</class>
               </emzee_multiskufilter>
           </helpers>
       </global>
   </config>
   ```
3. In the observer class `app/code/local/Emzee/MultiSkuFilter/Model/Observer.php` you receive the grid block. Find the `sku` column and **define a filter condition callback** which will be used to query the database when you filter by `sku`:

   ```
   <?php

   class Emzee_MultiSkuFilter_Model_Observer
   {
       public function adminhtmlCatalogProductGridPrepareMassaction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
       {
           $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
           $column = $block->getColumn('sku');
           $column->setData('filter_condition_callback', array(
               Mage::getResourceModel('emzee_multiskufilter/filter'), 'multiSkuFilter'
           ));
           return $this;
       }
   }
   ```
4. In the filter callback `app/code/local/Emzee/MultipleSkuFilter/Model/Resource/Filter.php`, split up the SKUs and **construct your SQL**. It's not the most elegant code but it works. By default the SKUs have to be an exact match but you also can search for `%test%` to use wildcards.

   ```
   <?php

   class Emzee_MultiSkuFilter_Model_Resource_Filter
   {
       public function multiSkuFilter($collection, $column)
       {
           if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
               return $this;
           }

           /**
            * @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $collection
            * @var Zend_Db_Select $select
            */
           $select = $collection->getSelect();
           $connection = $collection->getConnection();
           $conditions = array();
           $skus = explode(' ', $value);
           foreach ($skus as $sku)  {
               $condition = $connection->quoteInto('`e`.' . $column->getIndex() . ' LIKE ?', $sku);
               $conditions[] = $condition;

           }

           $sql = implode(' ' . Zend_Db_Select::SQL_OR . ' ', $conditions);
           $select->where($sql);
           return $this;
       }

   }
   ```

This is what the **result** looks like:

[image: Grid without filtering]

[image: Filtering by 2 SKUs]

[image: Filtering by exact match]

[image: Filtering by wild card]

Comment: nice solution, but why do you write custom SQL instead of using magentos addAttributeToFilter() method?

Comment: These are multiple OR clauses enclosed by an AND clause. Wasn't sure if that can be easily done with `addAttributeToFilter`?

Comment: Theoretical it should work like here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7908/multi-conditionals-or-and-and-inside-and-in-addattributetofilter but I wasn't able to reproduce this