# Magento collection where (a AND b) OR (c and d)

Tags: database, collection

I have a collection `$c`. If I write

```
$c->addFieldToFilter('id',array(1,2,3,4))
  ->addFieldToFilter('sku',array('a','b','c','d'));
```

The resulting SQL WHERE-part will be:

```
 WHERE (((id = '1') OR (id = '2') OR (id = '3') OR (id = '4'))) AND (((sku = 'a') OR (sku = 'b') OR (sku = 'c') OR (sku = 'd')))
```

What I would need is

```
WHERE (id = '1' AND sku = 'a') OR (id ='2' AND sku = 'b') OR ...
```

Can I do this with Magento collections? How?

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate. The other answer is about OR inside AND, this is about AND inside OR. (note the AND and OR are switched in the condition)

Answer (score 8):

According to the link provided by meenakshi, the right way is:

```
     $collection->addFieldToFilter(
        array('title', 'content'),
        array(
            array('like'=>'%$titlesearchtext%'), 
            array('like'=>'%$contentsearchtext%')
        )
    )
```

The where clause will result in:

```
WHERE title LIKE '%$titlesearchtext%' OR content LIKE '%$contentsearchtext%'
```

If you still have some doubts go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826474/magento-addfieldtofilter-two-fields-match-as-or-not-and/7851884#7851884">here

Answer (score 5):

You can do it as follows:

```
$c
  ->getSelect()
  ->where("id = '1' AND sku = 'a'")
  ->orWhere("id ='2' AND sku = 'b'")
   ...
```

---

**Update: You can use built in zend framework SQL protection as follows:**

```
$c
  ->getSelect()
  ->where("id = ? AND sku = ?", $var1, $var2)
  ->orWhere("id = ? AND sku = ?", $var3, $var4)
   ...
```

(according to the following SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18889623/2115770)

New code is untested but should work.

---

I'm not sure why anybody would flag this answer for deletion, since it's the only correct answer given.

Comment: This works, but it kills a lot of magento logic which depends on collections. Beside this you are open for SQL-Injections if you make it wrong - and EVERYONE makes it wrong.

Comment: All other answers are incorrect, this is the only one that does what has been asked (nested AND inside OR). I agree regarding SQL vulnerability, so if anyone knows a better method they should add a new answer. Otherwise I'd of course recommend to sanitize user input if any.

Comment: Question uses quoted strings by the way, not variables. So looking at the question SQL injection isn't relevant.

Comment: Even if the question is showing the reality (which I doubt) the next one looking for an answer will write vulnerable code :-)

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/7908/217

Comment: I agree. The question asked here however is to have a nested AND statement inside an OR statement. So (a=a AND b=b) OR (c=c AND d=d). NOT (a=a OR b=b) AND (c=c OR d=d). Looking at the link you refer to I can't find the answer to this.

Comment: I did update the question with zend placeholder syntax by the way, which should prevent SQL injection

Comment: You can nest the arrays to a deeper level, so you can mix whatever you want like this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98915/217

Comment: I don't think it's possible that way. The example only shows an AND clause with nested OR, not the other way around. If you know how to do it, please post here because I'd love to know :)

Comment: Dont have time atm, but the idea is: you just nest arrays like [[[],[],[]], [], []] and depending on the level, the items are OR or AND concatenated. Will check when I have time.

Comment: Alright, no hurry. For as far as I know, nesting arrays only results in OR clauses though, not in AND clauses. It might not be possible using Magento collection methods.

Comment: `->where("id = ? AND sku = ?", $var1, $var2)` esults in both question marks taking $var1

Comment: Would multiple where statements not also do the trick? `                foreach ($morewords as $word) {
                    $collection->getSelect()->where("sku LIKE ?", '%'.$word.'%');`

Answer (score 2):

You can use OR condition as following code

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
                array('attribute'=>'id', array('eq' => '1')),
                array('attribute'=>'sku',  array('eq' => 'a'))));
```

Refer this [**Link**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7908/multi-conditionals-or-and-and-inside-and-in-addattributetofilter)

Comment: I get ((Array = '') OR (Array = ''))

Comment: This is nice answered!

Comment: Doesn't work, @Rusit0 works.