# multiple AND & OR conditions in collection

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have a statement that would be really easy to write out (see below) but I can't seem to figure it out for Magento. The statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM addresses
WHERE
    $postcode_from BETWEEN (pc_from AND pc_to)
    OR $postcode_to BETWEEN (pc_from AND pc_to)
    OR (
        $postcode_from <= pc_from
        AND $postcode_to >= pc_to
    )
```

Is this going to be possible or am I going to have to write out the statement and manually feed it to Magento?

**EDIT***

Here's what I've got currently. It works but is messy:

```
$select = $read->select()->from($table);
$select->where(
    $read->quoteInto(" ( ? >= postcode_from", $upload['postcode_from']) .
    $read->quoteInto(" AND ? <= postcode_to )", $upload['postcode_from']) .
    $read->quoteInto(" OR ( ? >= postcode_from ", $upload['postcode_to']) .
    $read->quoteInto(" AND ? <= postcode_to )", $upload['postcode_to']) .
    $read->quoteInto(" OR ( ? <= postcode_from ", $upload['postcode_from']) .
    $read->quoteInto(" AND ? >= postcode_to )", $upload['postcode_to'])
);

$selection = $read->fetchAll($select);
```

**EDIT**

For anyone confused as to what I am trying to achieve:

I have `pc_from_1` and `pc_to_1`. these are stored in the database.

I also have `pc_from_2` and `pc_to_2`. These are from user input.

I want to check if any of the following occurs:

```
// Where this
      pc_from_1           pc_to_1
         |-------------------|
pc_from_2       pc_to_2
   |--------------|

//or this
      pc_from_1           pc_to_1
         |-------------------|
                 pc_from_2            pc_to_2
                    |--------------------|

// Or this
      pc_from_1           pc_to_1
         |-------------------|
pc_from_2                         pc_to_2
   |---------------------------------|
// occurs
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use this:

```
<?php
$postcode_from = 'your_from_number';
$postcode_to = 'your_to_number';
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection');
$collection
    ->addFieldToFilter('postcode', array('gteq' => $postcode_from))
    ->addFieldToFilter('postcode', array('lteq' => $postcode_to))
    ;

foreach($collection as $item)
{
   echo $item->getPostcode()."<br>";
}
```

This should give you list of postcode between the range.

**UPDATE**

To have multiple OR conditions:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
        'postcode',
        array(
            array('gteq' => $postcode_from),
            array('lteq' => $postcode_to)
        ),
        array(
            array('lteq' => $postcode_from), 
            array('gteq' => $postcode_to)  
        )
    );
```

[Check this for ref.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7908/multi-conditionals-or-and-and-inside-and-in-addattributetofilter#answer-7909)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this only covers one of the BETWEENs. I need to check both BETWEENs and the final `lteq` and `gteq` statements  too but wwith OR conditions between each one

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: I have just updated my answer to show what I am trying to achieve. I hope this makes more sense now

Answer (score 1):

The condition you described can be simplified to `pc_from_1 >= pc_from 2 OR pc_to_1 <= pc_to_2`. This way you don't need to check for all three cases separately.

You can combine conditions on different fields with OR, using the following syntax:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    ['postcode_from', 'postcode_to'],
    [['gteq' => $upload['postcode_from'], ['lteq' => $upload['postcode_to']]);
```

- First parameter: array of fields
- Second parameter: array of conditions