# addFieldToFilter() method with OR conditions between groups of fields with AND conditions inside

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to get the SQL condition like this:

> WHERE (
>   (field_1 = 'a' AND field_2 = 'b')
>    OR 
>   (field_1 = 'c' AND field_2 = 'd')
>    OR ...
>   ) ?

using `addFieldToFilter()` method?

I know about `getSelect()` method. The question about `addFieldToFilter` method only.

Answer (score 0):

Hey In my knowledge we can do it not same as you mentioned in your question but yes likely we can do it as:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=> 'someattribute','like' => 'value'),
        array('attribute'=> 'otherattribute','like' => 'value'),
        array('attribute'=> 'anotherattribute','like' => 'value'),
    )
);
```

here in array we need to specify the attribute and value and it will give you output as in where clause like:

```
WHERE ((someattribute LIKE 'value') OR (otherattribute LIKE 'value') OR (anotherattribute LIKE 'value'))
```

For more information you can look into [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7908/multi-conditionals-or-and-and-inside-and-in-addattributetofilter) answer too.Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, but I asked about addFieldToFilter method, not addAttributeToFilter. I use a simple (not-EAV) collection.