# AND inside OR in where condition in getCollections()

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

Need to generate the following query with **getCollection()** however unable to figure it out.

`(id_path = '12/xyz')` **OR** `(request_path = '/abc' AND store_id = '1')`

Tried the following but I need it the other way:

`//gives (...)` **AND** `(.. OR ..)`

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('id_path', '12/xyz');
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    array('store_id', 'request_path'), 
    array('1', '/abc')
 );
```

Comment: you can check this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7908/multi-conditionals-or-and-and-inside-and-in-addattributetofilter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this collection

```
$subSelect = clone $collection;
$subSelect->addFieldToFilter('request_path', '/abc')->addFieldToFilter('store_id', 1);
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    array('id_path', 'entity_id'),
    array(
        array('eq' => '12/xyz'),
        array('in' => $subSelect->getAllIds()),
    )
);

var_dump($collection->getSelect()->__toString());
```

Comment: Hey, thanks - that looks like a way to do it without having to write raw where SQL.

Comment: Well it was just for debugging, the var_dump line